# Sitecore JSS is logging complete Layout data on node Proxy

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk

Our log data on proxy server is increasing because Sitecore JSS is logging complete layout service data in logs, we want to know if there is a way to stop logging.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Sitecore documentation, Logging is turned off by default and can be conditionally turned on by using the `DEBUG` environment variable.

You can be selective and show only a specific category of log messages, for example, layout service logs.

```
DEBUG=sitecore-jss:layout
```

You need to verify that if you have enabled all the logs. Follow this article for more information.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/debug-logging-in-jss-apps.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: We tried to check if any environment variable is defined any where but we are not able to see it any where. @Sumit Is there a way to find from where it gets log to debug the issue.